# Nginx location not works correctly

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

i have location:

```
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://api:$api_port;
  }
```

Theory:

- `/api` must match
- `/api/` must match
- `/api/lol` must match
- `/apiqqqq` must NOT match

Practice:

- `/api` match
- `/api/` match
- `/api/lol` match
- `/apiqqqq` match (but must not match)

What am I doing wrong? How to make `/apiqqqq` not match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` is working correctly. To make your logic work, you will need to use a regular expression or two location blocks.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/api(/|$) { ... }
```

Or:

```
location = /api { ... }
location /api/ { ... }
```

Note that the order of evaluation of regular expression `location` blocks is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.